# How to stop downloading PDF file form iframe in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to upload a PDF for only view but the problem is the user is able to 
download the PDF file. I am using `<iframe src='path of file'></iframe>` tag.

Comment: If you do not want to have people download your stuff, then do not put it on the web. In any case please visit the [help] to see what and how toask

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent this :)
and even if you could nothing stops the user to make print screens etc.

if you want to view only then best to render your pdf with js using something like https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/